# Disable a logger conditionally based on the call stack

Tags: java, log4j

I have a web-service with a couple of other web-services as dependencies.  One of these dependencies is a service I'm sending small unimportant bits of data to every 15 seconds.  I'm sending vital pieces of data to the other dependency every 10 minutes.  I would prefer to see log lines from the calls that happen every 10 minutes, but not the calls that happen every 15 seconds (which make my logs really noisy).

The problem is both calls are made using the same third-party class: httpclient.  The log lines look like this:

```
27 Mar 2013 18:14:54,001 [DEBUG]  (main) httpclient.wire.content: blah blah blah
```

I've tried playing around with [NDC](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#Nested_Diagnostic_Contexts), but couldn't figure out how to configure my loggers thresholds based on the diagnostic context on top of the stack.

Any ideas?

Comment: So - do you want to disable/enable loggers in YOUR application, based on the webservice you call? - Did i get that correct?

Comment: No; I want to disable the logger sometimes, and enable it other times, depending on where I am calling it from.  All of this is happening in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put httpclient.wire.content logger level to at least WARN and put a log call before send the vital data.

Comment: This is the best practical answer so far, but I need the actual wire logs from httpclient for auditability purposes.

Comment: Make two appenders. One httpclient.wire.content is WARN and the other it is DEBUG.

Comment: How do I decide which one to use?

Comment: If I have two appenders, how do I decide in the code which calls httpclient which one I want to use, this time?  I could have class A wrapping httpclient which I want to use appender A (the loud one) and then class B wrapping httpclient which I want to use appender B (the quieter one).  What code can instruct httpclient, in A and B, which appender to use?

Comment: You do that configuring the log framework. No need to create wrappers or to instruct httpclient. Are you familiar with logs framework?

Comment: Yes.  I need a different appender to be active based on which class is using httpclient; read the title of my question.  As far as I can tell, I can't configure this through the log4j framework.  If there is a way, please include that configuration code in your answer.

Comment: I am saying you don't need to do it conditionally. One appender logs all to audit.log file for audit purposes. The second logs the 10 minutes sent data to all.log file.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, sorry for misunderstanding.  However, I'm interested in a way to get this information into the same log file, assuming this is possible.

Comment: It should be possible. But I think you will have to write your own Appender, maybe extend a existing one, check the stack and decide if it should be logged or not. But you may find performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn on/off logging or change log levels after you make the call with vital data, you can do something like this

```
LogManager.getLogger(Class.forName("httpclient.wire.content"))‌​.setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Changing the Level for the class should change the Logging for that particular class.

FYI - `LogManager.getCurrentLoggers();` should return all your Loggers

Comment: This doesn't work because my program is multithreaded; the 15 second request could be happening at the same time as the 10 minute request.  I want log messages from one and not the other.

Comment: @CoryKendall how about using lock to avoid multithreaded problem?

Comment: @JintianDENG This is an interesting idea, but I can't justify using a lock to control something as simple and low-level as logging.  I would give up before I worried about complications arising from a lock.